# BBCode to XHTML: Two possibilities, one regex?

Tags: regex, xhtml, bbcode

I'm writing a small blog module. I want the users to be able to type BBCode. I need to convert that to XHTML to store in the DB, which I managed to do for most of the tags, except for `[url]`.

There are two cases I want to allow:

```
[url=http://stackoverflow.com/]
```

which should be converted to

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">http://www.stackoverflow.com</a>
```

and

```
[url=http://stackoverflow.com/]StackOverflow[/url]
```

which should be converted to

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" title="StackOverflow">StackOverflow</a>
```

Sadly, I have been unable to do that. The results where horrible, and I'm wondering if this could be done in one regex or if it has to be split in two.

Comment: I'm sorry, this looks horrible but apparently even though I escaped the characters, and in the preview it looks fine, the result is not so good.

Comment: What regex engine will you be using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
\[url\s*=\s*([^\]]*)]\s*((?:(?!\s*\[/url\]).)*)\s*\[/url\]|\[url\s*=\s*([^\]]*)]
```

Replacement pattern:

```
<a href="$1$3" title="$2">$2$3</a>
```

Tested with this input:

```
bla [url=http://stackoverflow.com/]StackOverflow[/url] bla
bla [url=http://stackoverflow.com/] bla
```

Returns:

```
bla <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" title="StackOverflow">StackOverflow</a> bla
bla <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" title="">http://stackoverflow.com/</a> bla
```

Note that in any case you may have to add some validation/escaping, as invalid XML characters (", <, > etc.) may "break" the tag contents.

Comment: This is indeed the way to do it with pure regex.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this ghastly piece of work should do it:

```
\[url=([^\]]+)\](?:([^\[]+)\[\/url\])?
```

Upon matching, this should place the url in $1 and the text in $2 if it has been specified. I didn't test this yet so it could require some tweaking.

Comment: This does indeed work, just tested it myself. If no text is specified, $2 is undef (in Perl anyways). And it matched both forms of urls fine.

Comment: This works only if you have a conditional statement afterwards, it doesn't work as replacement pattern because of the optional BB end tag.

Answer (score 0):

Analize function BBCode2HTML($text)

https://code.google.com/p/pwision/source/browse/trunk/inc/BBCode.inc#150

The algorithm to transform BBCode 2 HTML is:
1) regulate the BBCode text
code here:
https://code.google.com/p/pwision/source/browse/trunk/inc/BBCode.inc#60

2) transform the regulated BBCode to XML
code here:
https://code.google.com/p/pwision/source/browse/trunk/inc/BBCode.inc#101

3)run a XSLT transformation to the XML text. 
The XSLT file is here
https://code.google.com/p/pwision/source/browse/trunk/inc/BBCodeXML2HTML.xslt
The transformation is done here:
https://code.google.com/p/pwision/source/browse/trunk/inc/BBCode.inc#113

Hope I helped!

PS: a good XSLT tutorial you can find here:
http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_languages.asp